# Unable to Implement the SwitchPreference with PreferenceScreen correctly and showing switch in action bar in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent, android-preferences

I am making settings of my app.

I want to show the settings like this

[image]

for which I have preferences

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<SwitchPreference
    android:key="isCallerIdOn"
    android:title="Caller ID" >
    <intent android:action=".activity.CallerIdSettings" />
</SwitchPreference>
```

On clicking caller Id it opens new screen

which is 
[image]

which has xml like

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:key="@string/isWarriorOn"
    android:layout="@layout/custom_pref_layout"
    android:summaryOff="@string/generic_off"
    android:summaryOn="@string/generic_on"
    android:title="@string/smsblocker" >
</CheckBoxPreference>
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:dependency="@string/isWarriorOn"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:key="@string/isSmsBlacklistOn"
    android:shouldDisableView="true"
    android:summaryOff="@string/generic_off"
    android:summaryOn="@string/generic_on"
    android:title="@string/myblacklist" >
</CheckBoxPreference>
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:dependency="@string/isWarriorOn"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:key="@string/isSmsCommunityFilterOn"
    android:summaryOff="@string/generic_off"
    android:summaryOn="@string/generic_on"
    android:title="Intelligent Content Filter" >
</CheckBoxPreference>
```

code is
switch_layout.xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
```

and 
switch_menu.xml is

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""/>
```

Now what I am stuck in is:

1.In 2nd screen which opens on clicking "callerId" by sending an intent it does not show action bar?

2.I need to show action bar with button whether it is on or off, as is in Wi-Fi
for this I have switch in Menu which is inheriting layout containing switch as given above.

I am unable to link that switch with code.